# Github Actions: Build docker image with a secret json file and env file

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I made a discord bot in python and inside that project there is a key.json file that I need because of firebase. I also have a .env file with different types of tokens mentioned trough out the code.

I tried to build a docker image using github actions but I couldn't figure out how I 'transfer' this key.json and .env file with my docker image without directly uploading these to the repo.

The important part is that the code needs a key.json file and .env file with the correct values because I use those values trough out the code!

Comment: You probably shouldn't bake secrets into the image, supply them at runtime instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How would I do that?

Comment: Well instead of an .env file, use _actual environment variables_ - look up how to do that for whichever platform you're running the container on in production. For files you can mount a volume - likewise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) for that. But if you really need them in a file just echo them from secret context into a file.

```
steps:
  - name: Echo secrets
    run: |
      echo -e '${{ secrets.key }}' >> key.json
      echo 'TOKEN1=${{ secrets.token1 }}' >> .env
      echo 'TOKEN2=${{ secrets.token2 }}' >> .env
```

A secret can be multi-line value, so you should be able to store structured value such as json.

Comment: Will these beadded to the .env file like
TOKEN='verylongsecrettoken'?

Comment: I just tried this but my key is a multiline json file so I tried encoding it with base64 but now it just says that the command is not found..

Comment: @Chin_077 I've updated answer for environment variables and json, you can see a working example here: https://github.com/frennky/github-actions-examples/blob/e846e5904b8ea363afc21e21b884d216baf22ff9/.github/workflows/multiline-variable.yml#L27